# Mail to Group in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I have read many responses to this question and none seems to have addressed the concern.
Multiple times people say, "just put the addresses in bcc: " Yes, we understand this would not show the email addresses BUT we want the people receiving the email to know it is coming to them as a group. Why not a simple preference in gmail: "when sending to group show/hide email addresses"

Any tips?

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't just mention that in the body of the e-mail?

Answer (score 1):

Use a mailing list.

My team has been using Yahoo Group mailing list for years to send emails among team members without having to type in their addresses one by one. All emails that are received show the mailing list address in the "to:" field so it's perfect for your requirement. And yes, all my team members are using Gmail email addresses so there is no problem if you and the recipients are not using Yahoo Mail.

p/s: I'm not sure if Google Group can do the same because I've never used it.

Comment: Yes, Google Groups can do the same. It can work as a mailing list, also known as *newsgroups* in the past.